# mat-select option weird behavior when add many options

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-material-5

I have a problem, I can't overlay the behavior of this element. 
This is the test case: click on test option and click test1 and then click again and click test5. and you will get output like this...

[image]

Here is the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select2-bhpjlv?file=app/select-hint-error-example.html

Thank you very much

Comment: Which browser, are you using?

Comment: i use chrome @Shohel

Comment: Which version of  angular material are you using? Its the problem of angular material, but in material 2, it has solved.

Comment: angular/material@5.2.4 @Shohel

Comment: hmmm, it has problem.

Comment: is it bug? or there is a mistake in by demo?

Comment: as far as i know, it is bug, many people has been created their issues to angular, this type of issues : https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5435